# How can I get the html of a website after a json request (Python)

Tags: python, jquery, json, python-requests

I'm data mining and a table has data added when you click on each row due to a jquery request. I need to, therefore, be able to get the html of the site after the button has been clicked.
I need to get each itinerary information by clicking on the cruises on this page https://www.cruisemapper.com/ships/AIDAmira-761?tab=itinerary

I could use selenium/ a simulated browser but the code needs to be fast as I have thousands of buttons I need to click. I am currently using requests in python to get the html but I cannot work out how to do this.

```py
import requests
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
url="https://www.cruisemapper.com/ships/AIDAmira-761?tab=itinerary"

page=requests(url, headers=headers)

html=page.text
```

I need to get the html for the site where I can access the data from the table after the additional data from the button click has been added.

Comment: Hello J. Instead of going the selenium route you would probably be better to simply emulate the network requests. Open up the chrome dev tools and go to networking tab. Click on one of those table rows on that page and take a look at the request as it appears in dev tools. Once you know how that works you can use requests to download the initial page. Use beautiful soup to find each row, grab whatever reference you need, then simulate the ajax request for that row using requests. I would highly recommend spoofing the user agent header when doing scraping to avoid detection.

Comment: Have a play around for an hour and show us what you come up with, we can help finish it off then if you get stuck.

Comment: I'll have a go, thanks

Comment: Cool, you may also need to inspect the DOM to figure out which field is the row id.

Comment: Actually, I think I have found a solution: